# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var location = 'RPXX0022'; // Find the code of your location in the following link and change this value between the single quotes: http://edg3.co.uk/snippets/weather-location-codes/
var unit = 'c';


var wq = "SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE location='" + location + "' AND u='" + unit + "'";
var cb = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1200 / 1000);
var wu = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(wq) + '&format=json&_nocache=' + cb;

window['ywcb'] = function(data) {
    var info = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
    var city = data.query.results.channel.location.city;
    var country = data.query.results.channel.location.country;
    $('.ywicon').addClass('wi-yw-' + info['code']);
    $('#ywloc').html(city + ", " + country);
    $('#ywtem').html(info.temp + '<span>' + '&deg;' + (unit.toUpperCase()) + '</span>');
};

$.ajax({
    url: wu,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'ywcb'
});
```

And it gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined

Comment: your response has the next structure `data.query.results.channel.units`, no `item` and no `location` fields, and it is better for you to use Chrome dev tools or Firebug before posting on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Check whether condition is there in item object

```
 var info = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
```

Additionally set a debugger in this line and check whether you are getting any value in info variable

Comment: i don't know what to do? can you help?tnx

Comment: are you using chrome ?

Comment: use the chrome Dev tools

Comment: go to the sources tab in that ,then on the left side you will see your js file from ,click on it and set breakpoints on it and then check what is the returned Json reponse when the execution runs in that

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging ..check this link on debugging for clear info